# Update client image after uploading with AsyncFileUpload Control in AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

I am uploading an image with AsyncFileUpload, it works well, but i want to show to the user the image which him just uploaded, but i am having troubles to make that work.

I have tried the OnClientUploadComplete event which receive sender and args paramenters, but the second paramenter only have the file name (without relative url), lenght, but not the file name after saved on the server.

I also tried ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock and call my own function in order to pass the url, but for some reason i can't select the img control with jquery, seems like that peace of code is executing in another instance of the page... not sure.

Please, if anyone have a solution or suggest, i do appreciate your answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put the same AsyncFileUpload control within invisible div 
or
add the following attributes to the  tag of your page:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"
```

Answer (score 0):

The script executes inside an iframe, you should locate the control using top.getElementById()

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when I have to generate new file name upon uploading /saving file at server side.
What I did to solve this is save the new generated file name into server side storage that client side can access it, viewstate of the page doesn't work, so you might use Session with the key name like CustomerID.

Then get the generated file name from client side, you can use call back to the same Session and get the file name, then apply it to the image control

```
    $('image').attr('src','displayimage.aspx?fileName=' + filename);
```

to get the image file stream and display it.
A bit tricky but it works.